# Vue.js sorting is not working when fetching from Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Currently this is for listing customer data from database. Data is fetching using Laravel 5. At present data is fetching and listing properly. This page contains pagination, filter search and sorting functionality. My problem is sorting is not working properly. Could you please help me to sort out this issue? I am using Vue.js version 1.0.25

**Here is the short code, only the sorting part**

```
View
<th v-for="key in columns" @click="sortBy(key)" :class="{active: sortKey == key}">
                            @{{ colTitles[key] }}
 </th>
<tr v-for="(index, item) in items | filterBy searchQuery | orderBy sortKey reverse">
........

JS
data: {
            sortKey: '',
            reverse: false,
.........
sortBy: function(sortKey) {
                this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;

                this.sortKey = sortKey;
            }
```

**Full code**

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="page-header">{{ trans('messages.customerListPageHeadingLabel') }}</h1>
            <div id="app">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <form id="search" class="form-inline">
                        <label for="query">{{ trans('messages.customerListPageSearchBox') }} </label>
                        <input name="query" class="form-control" v-model="searchQuery">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br>
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th v-for="column in columns" @click="sortBy(column)">
                            @{{ colTitles[column] }}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(index, item) in items | filterBy searchQuery | orderBy sortKey reverse">
                        <td>@{{ item.erp_id }}</td>
                        <td>@{{item.firstname}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{ url('/customer/details/') }}/@{{ item.id }}">@{{item.lastname}}</a></td>
                        <td>@{{item.email}}</td>
                        <td>@{{item.phone_1}}</td>
                        <td>@{{item.status}}</td>
                        <td>@{{item.created_on}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li v-if="pagination.current_page > 1">
                            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous"
                               @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li v-for="page in pagesNumber"
                            v-bind:class="[ page == isActived ? 'active' : '']">
                            <a href="#"
                               @click.prevent="changePage(page)">@{{ page }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page">
                            <a href="#" aria-label="Next"
                               @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
public function listCustomers()
    {
        $results =  Customer::select('id', 'erp_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone_1', 'status', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') AS created_on"))
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->latest()->paginate(25);

        $response = [
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $results->total(),
                'per_page' => $results->perPage(),
                'current_page' => $results->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $results->lastPage(),
                'from' => $results->firstItem(),
                'to' => $results->lastItem()
            ],
            'data' => $results
        ];

        return $response;
    }
```

**Vue JS**

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data: {
            sortKey: '',

            reverse: false,

            columns: ['erp_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone_1', 'status', 'created_on'],

            colTitles: {'erp_id':'@lang('messages.customerListPageTableCustomerNo')', 'firstname':'@lang('messages.customerListPageTableFirstname')', 'lastname':'@lang('messages.customerListPageTableLastname')', 'email':'E-Mail', 'phone_1':'@lang('messages.customerListPageTablePhone')', 'status':'Status', 'created_on':'@lang('messages.customerListPageTableAddedDate')'},

            pagination: {
                total: 0,
                per_page: 7,
                from: 1,
                to: 0,
                current_page: 1
            },

            offset: 4,// left and right padding from the pagination <span>,just change it to see effects

            items: []
        },

        ready: function () {
            this.fetchItems(this.pagination.current_page);
        },

        computed: {
            isActived: function () {
                return this.pagination.current_page;
            },
            pagesNumber: function () {
                if (!this.pagination.to) {
                    return [];
                }
                var from = this.pagination.current_page - this.offset;
                if (from < 1) {
                    from = 1;
                }
                var to = from + (this.offset * 2);
                if (to >= this.pagination.last_page) {
                    to = this.pagination.last_page;
                }
                var pagesArray = [];
                while (from <= to) {
                    pagesArray.push(from);
                    from++;
                }

                return pagesArray;
            }
        },

        methods: {
            fetchItems: function (page) {
                var data = {page: page};
                this.$http.get('/list/customers', data).then(function (response) {
                    //look into the routes file and format your response
                    this.$set('items', response.data.data.data);
                    this.$set('pagination', response.data.pagination);
                }, function (error) {
                    // handle error
                });
            },
            changePage: function (page) {
                this.pagination.current_page = page;
                this.fetchItems(page);
            },
            sortBy: function(sortKey) {
                this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;

                this.sortKey = sortKey;
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

the last parameter of `orderBy` should be `1` or `-1`, while you provide either `true` or `false` with the value of `reverse`

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/spwwxLvy/

change this:

```
this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;
```

to this:

```
this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? 1 : -1;
```

also change the initial value in `data()` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where should I add, here is the short code                                        View
<th v-for="key in columns" @click="sortBy(key)" :class="{active: sortKey == key}">
                            @{{ colTitles[key] }}
 </th>
<tr v-for="(index, item) in items | filterBy searchQuery | orderBy sortKey reverse">
........

JS
data: {
            sortKey: '',
            reverse: false,
.........
sortBy: function(sortKey) {
                this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;

                this.sortKey = sortKey;
            }

Comment: of course it is working. Change the value of `direction` to `1` (and click 'Run' in the upper left) to sort ascending, then change it to `-1` and it will sort in reverse.

But when it's `false`, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited but it is sorting only one time. When I click again it won't work. At present data(reverse: false).

Comment: I have found sorting feature in vue js website "https://vuejs.org/examples/grid-component.html". But I have not too much experience in vue js to merge this sorting feature with my code. If it possible could you please help me for merging this code?